# Sequelize query specific belongsToMany association

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js, has-and-belongs-to-many

I have a Sequelize setup with two tables, `Foo` and `Bar`. They each have a belongsToMany association with one another.

```
Foo.belongsToMany(Bar, {through: 'foo_bars'});
Bar.belongsToMany(Foo, {through: 'foo_bars'});
```

Now, I have some foos that are associated with many bars. But I have some specific bars, and I would like to find all foos that are associated with all of these, but only these, bars.

```
bars = [wineBar, beerBar];
const wineAndBeerBarFoo = await Foo.findAll({
    where: {
        // ?
    },
    include: [{
        model: Bar,
        where: {
            // id: {[Sequelize.Op.all]: [wineBar.id, beerBar.id]}
        }
    }]
});
```

I have tried some variations, but the thing I have commented in the include block's where is obviously incorrect, because it will look for foos that are associated with a bar whose ID is an array of the beer and wine bar IDs, which is impossible.

I'm not really seeing a way to accomplish what I'm looking for in the documentation. I could always go manually through the FooBars table, but was wondering if there's a more idiomatic way of doing this. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You should put a `where` clause to `through` object. I tried to use you condition with `Op.all` but I got `SequelizeDatabaseError: malformed array literal` so maybe `all` condition is broken in my version(I use `sequelize 5.8.5`). Maybe try some different approach to query (`Op.and` maybe). But basic principle is this:

```
const wineAndBeerBarFoo = await Foo.findAll({
    include: [{
        model: Bar,
        required: true,
        through: {
                where: {
                    BarId: {[Sequelize.Op.eq]: wineBar.id }
                }
            }
        }
    ]
});
```

Comment: I don't think the `all` condition is broken. Rather, the issue is that I'm trying to query an object by multiple associations. Each individual association, of course, only has one id, but my query is to assert that the set of all associations exactly matches my array of `[wineBar.id, beerBar.id]`.

Comment: Another option is a to remove `through` clause from Bar and use Sequelize literal in a `where` clause for Foo with your `ALL` condition, but I think it is not proper use of all operator. Can you achieve a proper data with a raw select?

Comment: With a raw select, I can query the `FooBars` table, selecting distinct `barId`s where the `barId` matches either wineBar's or beerBar's, group it by `fooId`, and then having the count of `barId`s equal 2.

Comment: So why not use a same principle with sequelize? Just set a model for foo_bar, set a model instead of string in a Foo and Bar model definition and start quering from FooBar (you have to set hasMany association from FooBar to Bar and Foo to make it work)